# uploading file from Gridview into Database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

There is Grid view having a file upload functionality, that upload the the image in to SQL Server Database. But while taking the control of file Upload entity it gives an error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Please help me to find the issue or give me some approach I follow to Implement the problem of uploading an image from grid view into database

Code file

```
if (e.CommandName == "upload")

            {
                string status = "";

                Button bt = (Button)e.CommandSource;
                GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)bt.Parent.Parent;
                TextBox amount = (TextBox)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("txtAmount");
                FileUpload doc = (FileUpload)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("passbookUpload");
                // FileUpload doc = (FileUpload)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("FileUpload");
                Label UdiseCode = (Label)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblUdiseCode");
                Label Remaining = (Label)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblremainingName");


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(amount.Text.Trim())
                    || string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.ToString())
                 )
                {

                    amount.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    doc.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;


                    //  box8.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('abc')", true);

                    return;
                }
                else
                {

                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(doc.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                    int fileSize = doc.PostedFile.ContentLength;

                    if (!(fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png") || (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
                   || (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".bmp") || (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif")
                     || (fileExtension.ToLower() == ""))
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('abc2|')", true);
                        doc.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        return;
                    }
                    Stream stream = doc.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                    Byte[] imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                    DL_Reimbursement.SaveReimbursementAmount(ddlSession.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddldistrict.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlBlock.SelectedValue.ToString(), UdiseCode.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(Remaining), Convert.ToInt32(amount), imageData, out status);
                    if (status == "INS")
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('abc3')", true);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('कृपया डाटा को जांच ले तथा दोबारा प्रयास करे!|')", true);
                    }

                }
}
```

aspx file for grid

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvFetchRecords" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" OnRowDataBound="gvFetchRecords_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GVBankAccDetails_RowCommand"
                                EmptyDataText="No Report Detail(s) were found !" PageSize="1000" AllowPaging="true">
                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#Container.DataItemIndex +1 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Udise Code" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblUdiseCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Udise_Code") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="School Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblUdiseName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("School_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="baaki rashi" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblremainingName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Remaining") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rashi added" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Style="Width: 130px;"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Document Upload" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>

                                               <asp:FileUpload ID="passbookUpload" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="सुरक्षित करे" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="govBtnS" Text="सुरक्षित करे" CommandName="upload" Style="Width: 100px;" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="डाउनलोड करे" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblDownload" runat="server" Text="डाउनलोड करे" CommandName="download" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("IsUpdated") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Image ID="gvImage" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(doc.PostedFile.FileName);
This line throw an error.
and while debug this line: FileUpload doc = (FileUpload)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("passbookUpload");
It aslo don't show anything, may be control issue. remaining variable get the respective value expect file upload type variable

Comment: `FileUpload doc = (FileUpload)grdRow.Cells[0].FindControl("passbookUpload");` will throw error coz `passbookUpload` is not in `Cell[0]`. I think it is in `Cells[5]`. That way you need to check for other controls too... You are using `Cells[0]` for all the controls... but not all of them are in `Cells[0]`. You need to use proper cell indexer to get the appropriate control.

Comment: I also change it to Cells[5], Still it shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the name of the ID of the File Upload. Sometimes it may create the problem